# Random quotes are being added to my lists

Tags: python

So I am currently trying to program a simple text based game, and I have a file based save system. I recently added cross file stealing(dont ask), and I tested it. After a few saves, I noticed the system designed to only allow one stealing between loading the stolen from save stopped working. I looked in my save file and saw
[this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GADY.png)

After a bit more, this happened to a different
[save file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MMn4.png)

And now there's an issue where the code deletes the contents of the save file!
Can anyone explain why the extra characters are being added? Ask if you need more of the code, this is just the save and rob functions.

code:

```
 import os
 import time
 import random as r

def savefile(data, slot):
        if(len(data)>6):
            savef=open("savefile"+str(slot)+".txt", 'w')
            print(data[6])
            data[6][0] = data[6][0].replace("'", '')
            data[6][2] = data[6][2].replace("'", '')
            print(data[6])
            if(len(data[5])==2):
                data[5].append(0)
            savef.write(str(data[0])+"\n"+str(data[1])+"\n"+str(data[2]).replace(" ", "")+"\n"+str(data[3])+"\n"+str(data[4])+"\n"+str(data[5])+"\n"+str(data[6]))
            savef.close()
        else:
            print("the save is outdated")


 def localrob(data):
        #UNFINISHED
        print("Choose your target(enter their ID)")
        savenum=1
        data[1]=int(data[1])
        while True:
            try:
                save=open("savefile"+str(savenum)+".txt", "r")
                name=save.read().split()[0]
                print("["+str(savenum)+"] "+name)
                savenum=savenum+1
                save.close()
            except:
                break
        try:
            target=int(input())
        except:
            print("wow thats not a number idiot")
            return data
        if(target==slotr):
            print("You cant rob yourself silly!")
            return data
        else:
            targetfile=open("savefile"+str(target)+".txt")
            targetdata=targetfile.read().split()
            if(targetdata[6][0]=='False'):
                pass
            else:
                print("This mans already been stolen from! Give em a rest!")
                targetfile.close()
                return data
            targetdata[1]=int(targetdata[1])
            bounty=r.randint(int(targetdata[1]/5), int(targetdata[1]/2))
            spend=r.randint(int(targetdata[1]/15), int(targetdata[1]/5))
            ques=input(targetdata[0]+" has " + str(bounty) + " coins up for grabs, but if you get lucky, you might be able to snag more. It will cost "+str(spend)+" coins. Do you go through? (y/n)")
            if ques.lower()=='y':
                extraspent=int(input("How much extra do you want to spend?"))
                if(int(data[1])-extraspent-spend<0):
                    print("lol ur too poor to rob them")
                    return data
                chances=int(300*(spend+extraspent)/bounty)-int(data[5][2])
                if(chances>100):
                    chances=100
                chances=chances-10
                ohmy=r.randint(0, 100)
                if(data[5][1]):
                    last=input("Your chances are "+str(chances)+"%. Are you sure you want to attack? (y/n)")
                    if(last=='y'):
                        pass
                    else:
                        print("Ok.")
                        return rob(data)
                print("You invested %s coins into this, it better go well." % (str(extraspent+spend)))
                print("Stealing all of "+targetdata[0]+" possesions...")
                time.sleep(r.randint(1, 10))
                print(targetdata[6])
                if ohmy==1:
                    print("Even though you didnt think so, you were able to get BASICACLLY EVERYTHING LMAO. You earn %s coins(after paying off your investment" % (str(targetdata[1])))
                    data[1]=int(data[1])+targetdata[1]
                    targetdata[6]=[True, data[0], targetdata[1]]
                    targetdata[1]=0
                elif ohmy<5:
                    print("You were able to steal twice what you think what you could.")
                    data[1]=int(data[1])+bounty*2-spend-extraspent
                    targetdata[1]=targetdata[1]-bounty*2
                    targetdata[6]=[True, data[0], bounty*2]
                elif ohmy<chances:
                    print("You successfully stole %s from this poor man, getting a net profit of %s coins." % (str(bounty), str(bounty-extraspent-spend)))
                    data[1]=int(data[1])+bounty-extraspent-spend
                    targetdata[1]=targetdata[1]-bounty
                    targetdata[6]=[True, data[0], bounty]
                elif ohmy<90:
                    print("Oof, you failed and lost your investment.")
                    data[1]=int(data[1])-extraspent-spend
                    targetdata[6]=[False, data[0], 0]
                else:
                    print("WOW, you got caught! You paid twice your investment.")
                    data[1]=data[1]-2*extraspent-2*spend
                    targetdata[6]=[False, data[0], 0]
                savefile(targetdata, target)
                targetfile.close()
                return data
        return data
        #UNFINISHED
```

Comment: Rather than rolling your on file format to serialize/deserialize, have you tried JSON or YAML?

Comment: Im new to using files, can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: @carbonice This isn't the place for other to "explain" universally-known file formats to you.  Study.

Comment: Have you read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in how you are turning bools and lists into strings.
`str(True)` will return `'True'`, but `str([True])` returns `'[True]'`.
If you call `str` twice like this `str([str(True)])` the output will be `"['True']"`. The list never contains the bool `True`, only the string `'True'`, written as `str(True)`, and treats it like any other string (for example `str(['Hello'])` returns `"['Hello']"`).

The same is true for ints and other non-string datatypes.
`str([str(0)]` becomes `"['0']"`.

Most likely the problem is that you are inconsistent in using `str([str(True)])` and `str([True])`, resulting in sometimes `"['True']"` and other times `'[True]'`.

Be careful about mixing up strings and bools.
`savefile(targetdata, target)` probably gives you an `AttributeError`. The value at targetdata[6][0] is a bool, but `savefile` starts by calling `.replace()` on it, which is a string method.

You can also try serializing data with python's built-in module pickle instead of writing it to a text file, which allows you to directly save variables to files.
You write data to a file using `pickle.dump` and read from it using `pickle.load`, like so:

If you want to save the list `data` to the file `saved_data.pkl`:

```
import pickle

with open("saved_data.pkl", "wb") as file:
# note the "b" in the second argument, it means you are opening the file to
# write to it in a binary format, not with text
    pickle.dump(data, file)
```

To load the data back from the file:

```
with open("saved_data.pkl", "rb") as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)
```